# CGAL exact number performance

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, cgal

I'm using CGAL for geometrical calculations. I need exact arithmetic operations (i.e. addition, subtraction, multiplication, divison) for my calculations. So my best solution so far is the following number type:

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Quotient<CGAL::MP_Float> > NT;
```

Then I should be able to perform exact arithmetic operations like:

```
NT a, b, c;
a = b + c;
```

Now I am a bit worried about the performance overhead of exact arithmetic compared to "standard" floating point arithmetic. How much worse is the performance of CGAL's exact number type compared to double? Does an upper bound exist that states how big the performance overhead could be maximally?

**EDIT** I should describe a bit more what I need to achieve. I want to implement triangle/triangle splitting in 3D space. So if two triangles are intersecting, then I want to split them on their intersection line.
Problems arise when I have very small triangles or when the intersection of both triangles is very small. This results in roundoff errors and my program crashes. I have tried to manage it using tolerance values but this only works in 99% of the time. And I want to write software that works in 100% of the time, so I really need exact computations.
I actually just need two things:

- An exact representation of a 3D vector.
- Exact predicates (regarding <, >, == operations)
- Exact arithmetic to calculate an intersection line between two triangles.

Regarding the intersection line caclulation, I have calculations like this:

```
public Vector3m ComputeLineIntersection(IntersectionLine& otherLine)
    {
        //x = x1 + a1*t = x2 + b1*s
        //y = y1 + a2*t = y2 + b2*s
        //z = z1 + a3*t = z2 + b3*s

        Vector3m linePoint = otherLine._point;
        Vector3m lineDirection = otherLine._direction;

        NT t;
        if ((_direction.Y * lineDirection.X - _direction.X * lineDirection.Y) != 0)
        {
            t = (-_point.Y * lineDirection.X + linePoint.Y * lineDirection.X + lineDirection.Y * _point.X - lineDirection.Y * linePoint.X) / (_direction.Y * lineDirection.X - _direction.X * lineDirection.Y);
        }
        else if ((-_direction.X * lineDirection.Z + _direction.Z * lineDirection.X) != 0)
        {
            t = -(-lineDirection.Z * _point.X + lineDirection.Z * linePoint.X + lineDirection.X * _point.Z - lineDirection.X * linePoint.Z) / (-_direction.X * lineDirection.Z + _direction.Z * lineDirection.X);
        }
        else if ((-_direction.Z*lineDirection.Y + _direction.Y*lineDirection.Z) != 0)
        {
            t = (_point.Z*lineDirection.Y - linePoint.Z*lineDirection.Y - lineDirection.Z*_point.Y +
                 lineDirection.Z*linePoint.Y)/(-_direction.Z*lineDirection.Y + _direction.Y*lineDirection.Z);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("Intersection line not correctly calculated.");
        }

        NT x = _point.X + _direction.X * t;
        NT y = _point.Y + _direction.Y* t;
        NT z = _point.Z + _direction.Z * t;

        return new Vector3m(x, y, z);
    }
```

Comment: Why not `typedef Kernel::FT NT;`? The overhead will be quite large. There is no upper bound, `double` has a constant size, while the size of rationals after many operations can grow arbitrarily large. In practice, we expect that interval arithmetic will be enough for most operations and the overhead will be a constant factor.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not mathematician. I've researched about CGAL's field number type and interval arithmetic but I'm still not sure what I should use now. So you mean I should use `typedef Kernel::FT NT;`. When I use this type, are the computations exact? Will the overhead be constant?

Comment: All I meant with `Kernel::FT` is that there is no point writing the complicated type your wrote for `NT`, the kernel already does a suitable typedef (possibly the same as yours depending on the availability of GMP). Yes, computations are exact. No number type can guarantee exact computation in constant time when cascading constructions. However, if all your triangles come from `double` coordinates, and you only intersect those, then in some sense the "depth" of constructions is low and the overhead is constant.

Comment: I see. I've implemented my triangle inersection algorithm using a rational datatype and without CGAL. The calculations are robust but inherently slow. So I was hoping that CGAL could speed up my calculations. So at the bottom line, CGAL does not bring performance improvements, right?

Comment: It does in practice. Lazy types use interval arithmetics as long as that's sufficient, and only do the slow exact rational computations in the rare cases where it is necessary. Why don't you just experiment and see if the performance suits you?

Comment: Ok, yes I will do that. Thanks Marc!

Comment: How much of performance difference between `double`  and `exact`?